# Converting a TensorFlow* Model

Tags: tensorflow, openvino

I want to convert my 1 tensorflow model to IR currently I am following the instructions here:
https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_convert_model_Convert_Model_From_TensorFlow.html

The model I use is meta graph and ubuntu 16.04

I ran the line deflected:
python3 mo_tf.py --input_meta_graph  .meta

then it will get an error:
[ERROR] Exception occurred during running replacer "None" (): Data flow edge coming out of AssignSub node model_0 / resnet_v1_50 / block4 / unit_1 / bottleneck_v1 / shortcut / BatchNorm / AssignMovingAvg

Can you guys please help me? thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Did you freeze the model before conversion? Please look at how to freeze your model using instructions from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py and retry.

Comment: I am having an error while freezing the model: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650165/freezing-tensorflow-model-into-a-pb-file                                                                   

Can you help me